# IIIS FTP Site not starting

Tags: windows, iis, iis-6, ftp

I am receiving the following error:

```
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Google has not yielded any useful results and I can seem to find anything in the event/IIS logs. Is there anyway I can get to the bottom of this issue?

I appreciate any help/suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the "FTP Publishing Service" (MSFTPSVC) is failing to start properly. Make sure the service is set for either manual or automatic startup (i.e. not disabled).

I'd consider making a backup of the metabase, removing the FTP service, and re-installing it. I believe your configuration will be maintained but having the metabase backup would insure it.

Failing that I suppose I'd watch MSFTPSVC.exe starting up w/ Process Monitor and see what it looks like it's doing.

Comment: Process Monitor did the job. BUFFER OVERFLOW on the MSFTPSVC Description. Thanks!